# .NET CF 3.5 why calling ShowDialog() twice works?

Tags: c#, showdialog, .net-cf-3.5

I had a problem in .net compact 3.5 where my dialog closed immediately after being shown with .ShowDialog(). Then I found a workaround to call it twice. It helped, but I have no idea why.
I mean why would executing the same operation twice would work any different, while the constructor code is only called once anyway.?

```
           try
            {
                //blinks the form (closes immediately)
                _activeChildView.ShowDialog();
                //shows dialog and blocks the thread until dialog is closed (woks as intended)
                _activeChildView.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch( Exception ex)
            {
                //no exception is ever caught there
            }
```

The first dialog result is DialogResult.None and the Closing event isn't called after the first showDialog.

Comment: show your _activeChildView constractor

Comment: it has single line: initilaizeComponent(). I think that if the problem were in the contructor the second ShowDialog call wouldn't work too?

Comment: The problem is definitely not in the code you showed. Show more.

Comment: Well I am not sure what to show you guys.. If the problem was in the code, I would get a exception when creating the object, not when showing it. There are no events or code associated with visibility or window state. Normally calling showDialog for the second time would cause a InvalidOperationException, but now when I call it for the second time it works as intended.and the first one doesn't.

Comment: Is the code you posted in an event handler?

Comment: Yup, that is a button click. I feel it has something to do with a threading. Invoking the code from the UI thread solves the problem, but does not answer my question :)